# mixing fractional Brownian motions

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, correlation, fractional-calculus

[first posted [here]](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/55040/mixing-fractional-brownian-motions)

Given two Brownian motions $W_t^1, W_t^2$, we can have them correlated by
$$W_t^1 = \rho  W_t^2+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z_t$$
where $W_t^{2}$ and $Z_t$ are independent of each other.

My question: is there any similar relationship between fractional Brownian motions? In other words, given $W_t^{H_2}, Z_t^{H_3}$ two independent fractional Bm, can we say anything about
$$\rho W_t^{H_2}+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z_t$$
or
$$\rho W_t^{H_2}+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z_t^{H_3}$$
for $H_2$ and $H_3$ not necessarily equal? Can they generate a new correlated fBm $W_t^{H_1}$?